# Display sum of all datalabels of each each bar stacks

Tags: python, python-pptx

How can I display sum of all the data labels above the bar stack as in the attached [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXDVK.png)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to sum them yourself, perhaps by using `chart.series.values` and place them in a separate text-box. There is no option in the chart itself to display summary values like this.